# How to scrape only prices less than x from craigslist

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have a bs4 **scraping** the used cars on craigslist. Right now it returns all postings but I am trying to get postings less than $2k. I know I either need a nested if statement or a separate function all together. any help?

```
# Loop through returned results
for result in results:
    # Error handling
    try:
        # Identify and return title of listing
        title = result.find('a', class_="result-title").text
        # Identify and return price of listing
        price = result.a.span.text
        # Identify and return link to listing
        link = result.a['href']

        # Print results only if title, price, and link are available
        if (price and title and link):
            print('-------------')
            print(title)
            print(price)
            print(link)
        next
    except AttributeError as e:
        print(e)
```

Comment: Hey welcome to Stack Overflow. I think you might want to clean up your second paragraph, as it is rather unintelligible.

Answer (score 0):

You could check to see if `int(price) >= 2_000` and skip printing if it is using `continue`:

```
for result in results:
    title = result.find('a', class_="result-title").text
    price = result.a.span.text
    link = result.a['href']

    try:
        if int(price) >= 2_000:
            continue
    except ValueError:
        continue


    if all(price, title, link):
        print('-------------')
        print(title, price, link, sep='\n')
```